# Is there a quick way to find a html element in my local directory?

Tags: html, directory, find

Is there a quick way to find a html element in my local directory?

I can't find the document where my div element has the

```
class="test123"
```

is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Notepad++. In the search menu is an entry "find in files" (or use the shortcut Ctr+Shift+F). It has several features like filtering to certain files extensions (**.html;*.js* may work in your case) or you can even use regular expressions.